# View bound not compatible with upper type bound?

Tags: scala

I have a method that takes a Comparable and returns a Comparable and wraps another method that does the same thing:

```
def myMethod[T <: Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = otherMethod(arg)
def otherMethod[T <: Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = arg
```

This compiles, but doesn't allow me to call myMethod with an Int or any other type that requires an implicit conversion to implement Comparable. As I understand it, view bounds are meant to address this type of problem, but using the view bound

```
def myMethod[T <% Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = otherMethod(arg)
```

I get the compiler error:

> inferred type arguments [T] do not conform to method otherMethod's type parameter bounds [T <: java.lang.Comparable[T]]

So far, the only workaround I've come up with is to use a second type parameter and cast between the two:

```
def myMethod[T <% Comparable[T], U <: Comparable[U]](arg: T): T =
  otherMethod(arg.asInstanceOf[U]).asInstanceOf[T]
```

This works, but it's ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

Would either of the following work?

1. Make the `T`'s view bound consistent in both methods,

   ```
   def otherMethod[T <% Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = arg
   def myMethod[T <% Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = otherMethod(arg)
   ```
2. Introduce a new type parameter `U <: Comparable[U]` and an implicit conversion from `T` to `U`,

   ```
   def otherMethod[T <: Comparable[T]](arg: T): T = arg
   def myMethod[U <: Comparable[U], T <% U](arg: T): U = otherMethod(arg)
   ```

The problem with your version is that `T <% Comparable[T]` converts `T` to type `Comparable[T]`, but this does not satisfy the recursive type `T <: Comparable[T <: Comparable[T <: ...]]` (*pseudocode*) that `otherMethod` expects.

---

*Update*. To use either `otherMethod` or `myMethod` with Scala's `Int`, you will need to help the type inferencer a little bit,

```
myMethod(2)                    // Int value types don't implement Comparable
myMethod(2: java.lang.Integer) // Apply implicit conversion (Int => java.lang.Integer)
```

---

*Update 2*. In the comments, you said you're willing to make `myMethod` a little uglier to improve type inference at the call site. Here's a way,

```
def myMethod[U <: Comparable[U], T](arg: T)
     (implicit ev1: T => U, ev2: T => Comparable[U]): U = otherMethod(arg)
myMethod(2) // returns java.lang.Integer(2)
```

The trick is to use two implicit conversions: `ev1` actually gets applied, and `ev2` is there only to aid type inference. The latter requires Scala to search its implicits for a conversion of type `Int => Comparable[U]`. In this case, only one such conversion can be found, which fixes `U = java.lang.Integer`.

By the way, try compiling this code with `scalac -Xprint:typer`. You'll see that the same implicit, `Predef.int2Integer`, is used for both `ev1` and `ev2` parameters.

*Side note*: it's best to avoid `asInstanceOf` casts because those defeat the soundness of the Scala type system.

Comment: 1. No, unfortunately otherMethod is defined in third party library.
2. Yes! This seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, i spoke too soon ... the second solution does compile, but i still can't call it with an Int. Here's the error: "type arguments [Int,Int] do not conform to method myMethod's type parameter bounds [U <: java.lang.Comparable[U],T]"

Comment: Isn't that also a problem with `otherMethod` defined in the third party library? I get the same error with `otherMethod(2)`.

Comment: Yes, i can't call otherMethod directly with an Int. That's partly what i want the wrapper method to take care of for me :)

Comment: I'd rather not have to specify java.lang.Integer when calling myMethod. If there has to be ugliness, it's better encapsulated within myMethod.

Comment: Re update 2: I agree this is better than using asInstanceOf. However, there's a problem: when otherMethod returns null i'm getting a NullPointerException (at scala.Predef$.Long2long(Predef.scala:304)). The asInstanceOf solution doesn't have this problem. It also concerns me slightly that the return type is different than the argument type, but so far i don't see any compilation errors because of that.

Comment: When I tried making `otherMethod` return null, I don't get an exception, I get `myMethod(2) == null: java.lang.Integer`. If you want `myMethod(2)` to return an `Int`, you could add another implicit conversion `U => T`, but then you would need to add special logic for handling the case that `U` is null.

Comment: I'm passing the return value of myMethod to another method that takes a Long. Apparently an implicit conversion turns that into 0 when using the asInstanceOf version, but throws an NPE with the update 2 version. Another difference i just noticed is that when i call myMethod with an Int and try to pass the result to a method that takes a Long, i get a compilation error with the update 2 version but not the asInstanceOf version. (Casting might be ugly, but it seems to be giving me the behavior i want.)

Comment: It seems dangerous to treat null as 0, why doesn't `otherMethod` just return 0? Scala's approach is more general and safer, but sometimes we're stuck with legacy Java code...